# Frontend Session Expired

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have a problem regarding Magento 2.3.2.
On some products detail pages, which uses AJAX to load some images, the customer gets an error, when adding product to cart - "Your session has expired".

The Magento Log und Apache Log has no error. 
Does Magento has any problems with Ajax Request via GET???

Answer (score 0):

No I think there is no issue with Magento session.

I think it might be issue with your server configuration. So I would suggest try to discuss the same thing with your server support team and still you have doubts you can setup this project in another server or local system. Again still you are facing the same issue then you should enable the developer mode and try to debug this issue.

Please let me know if you need my help.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Error “Your session has expired” when click on add to cart

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://127.0.0.1/zain/accessories/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url';

UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://127.0.0.1/zain/accessories/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

after that run command in your terminal

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Reference link 
[Error "Your session has expired" when click on add to cart in magento 2.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291489/error-your-session-has-expired-when-click-on-add-to-cart-in-magento-2-3)

Comment: It is exactly the same problem like discussed here:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58139660/magento-2-form-key-works-wrong-with-full-page-cache
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13746