# Error "Your session has expired" when click on add to cart in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, error, addtocart, session

I am new in magento, I am creating website in magento 2.3 and I have installed `FreeGo` theme in my magento website. But

> when i click on product's `add to cart` then it's giving me
>   **error-->** ***`Your session has expired`.***

I have google it a lot but didn't find any solution.

**Here is the screenshot:**

[image]
How can i get rid of this and product can add to cart? **Please help me**

**Update:**
[image]

Comment: You can try to create a virtual domain name.

Comment: what is your url ?please update in question

Comment: @SavanPatel It's in my localhost, `http://localhost/zain/accessories/`

Comment: @MichaelHa virtual domain, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.***

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://127.0.0.1/zain/accessories/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url';

UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://127.0.0.1/zain/accessories/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

***http://127.0.0.1/zain/accessories/ in this write your frontend url (home page url) what you have***

***after that run command in your terminal***

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: where should i put this code?

Comment: run code in your database

Comment: I am using `Phpmyadmin`, so magento database, or in parent for all?

Comment: what is home page url (frontend url) this one http://localhost/zain   ?

Comment: No, It's `http://localhost/zain/accessories/`  **accessories** folder is my magento website

Comment: open phpmyadmin = > select your database = > then click on SQL and run  this code

Comment: yes I did this now, I have run those 2 queries and i am trying to run `http://127.0.0.1/zain/accessories/` in web url but it's redirecting me to `http://localhost/zain/accessories/`, and I have updated my question with screenshot that I have run that queries

Comment: @ZainShabir did you run this 2 (two) sql query?

Comment: yes, as u said to run those 2 queries

Comment: @ZainShabir okay then clear and flush your cache also clear browser cache & cookie   then check again

Comment: yes, I did, but still not working, even This is working `http://127.0.0.1/` and `http://127.0.0.1/zain/` but when i open `http://127.0.0.1/zain/acessories/` the n it's redirecting me to `http://localhost/zain/acessories/`

Comment: okay then run command in your terminal => php bin/magento cache:clean,
php bin/magento cache:flush,
php bin/magento indexer:reindex,
php bin/magento setup:upgrade,
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: These all commands?

Comment: yes run one by one

Comment: Worked after running only `php bin/magento cache:clean`, now, do i need to run those other commands or it's not necessary now?

Comment: not necessary now enjoy

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. Have a good day

Answer (score 1):

You also can try to set correct domain in path `web/cookie/cookie_domain` in `core_config_data` table. (it's domain name, so no `http(s)://` and no `/` at end)

Answer (score 0):

In case if you don't work in local than it must be your SSL issue. Do active SSL and then open the site with https and then try to add a product in cart. This will fix your problem for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for **Magento ≥ 2.3.7**:

```
bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_storefront 0
bin/magento cache:clean
```

[mage2.pro/t/6364](https://mage2.pro/t/6364)

Another message for the same error is «[**Session size of** <…> **exceeded allowed session max size of** <…>](https://mage2.pro/t/6363)»